# Problema al eliminar datos de mi base de datos

Tags: java

estoy realizando una práctica de crud con swing, Java y jpa. Es un sistema de un hotel donde en una tabla guardo las reservas y en otra tabla los datos del huésped, la tabla de huésped a su vez tiene la relación OneToOne con la tabla reservas.
Mi problema es que a la hora de eliminar un dato seleccionando me salta el siguiente error:
"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails"
Si alguien me da una mano para arreglar el problema. Muchas gracias

Comment: verifica bien si al momento de eliminar no estas borrando un dato donde dependan de ese registro, si dieras el diagrama de tus tablas y el comando sql que estas ejecutando seria de mucha utilidad, para mí que estas borrando un registro que está siendo utilizada por otras como llave foránea.

Comment: Hola, la tabla Huéspedes tiene como llave foránea el ID de la tabla reservas ya que en el ejercicio se debe poder realizar una búsqueda por num. de reserva que sería el mismo id de la tabla reserva

Comment: Ahí tienes el problema. Si estas intentando eliminar un registro de reservas cuyo id este asociado a un huésped jamás te va a dejar realizar el borrado. La eliminación a la inversa si debería funcionarte correctamente, eliminar el huésped y luego la reserva.

Comment: El problema persiste al realizar el proceso inverso. Si intento eliminar el registro huesped primero me sale el siguiente error: 
"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (hotelalura.huesped, CONSTRAINT FK_HUESPED_NUMRESERVA_ID FOREIGN KEY (NUMRESERVA_ID) REFERENCES reserva (ID)

y si intento eliminar el registro reserva primero sale el mismo mensaje.

Comment: amigo te recomiendo que hagas lo que te comentaba en mi primer comentario, retroalimenta tu pregunta agregando visualmente el diagrama y el comando con el que estas queriendo eliminar los datos de las tablas, de esta manera no te van a borrar tu pregunta algún administrador.